# PHP preg_replace not replacing \r\n when called from included file

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using Linux (14.04.2 LTS trusty).

In my PHP script, I output data (varchar) retrieved from several columns within a MySQL table.

The data in some columns contains new lines/paragraphs, spaces, periods, and many other characters.  For example, here is one of the values I am working with:

`var_dump($value2)` shows `string(16) "\r\n\r\nredness."`

For some columns, I enter the following code to remove certain unwanted data before outputting...

```
$value3 = preg_replace('#[ \,\";\.\n\r]#', '', $value2);
echo $value3;
```

which outputs: `redness` ...it works.

Realizing that I use the code above often (along with additional code not presented here), I decided to create a function that includes it and then call the function (which is included from another file) to output the remaining columns.

However, when I call the function, `\n` and `\r` does not seem to work and the output displays those characters literally:

`\r\n\r\nredness`

Based on answers to related questions in this forum, I tried the following:

`$value3 = preg_replace('#[ \\\r|\\\r\\\n|\\\n|\,|\"|;|\.]#', '', $value2);`

which outputs: `edess`

focusing on the `\r` and `\n`, I tried `$value3 = preg_replace('#[\r\n]+#', '', $value2);`

which outputs: `\r\n\r\nredness`.

I also tried `$value3 = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $value2);`

which outputs: `\r\n\r\nredness.`

I tried `$value3 = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $value2));`

which outputs: `\r\n\r\nredness.`

I tried `$value3 = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value2);`

which outputs: `\r\n\r\nredness.`

I tried `echo preg_replace('/[\r\n]/','',$value2);`

which outputs: `\r\n\r\nredness.`

I tried `echo preg_replace('/(\\r)(\\n)/','',$value2);`

which outputs `\r\n\r\nredness.`

**Why does preg_replace not remove `\r` and/or `\n` if I call it from a function within an included file?**

Comment: Simply try `echo preg_replace('/[\r\n]/','',$your_str);`

Comment: @Uchiha I tried `echo preg_replace('/[\r\n]/','',$value2);`, and the output is `\r\n\r\nredness.`

Comment: Post your input string

Comment: Try as `/(\\r)(\\n)/`

Comment: @Uchiha I tried `echo preg_replace('/(\\r)(\\n)/','',$value2);` which outputs `\r\n\r\nredness.`

Comment: Please post your input string

Comment: `var_data($value2)` is actually `var_dump($value2)` ? If yes, then the output suggests, that $value2 does not contain line-feed/-break characters but actually a backslash followed by  `r` and backslash followed by `n`.

Comment: @VolkerK corrected typo to `var_dump($value2)`.

Comment: see my updated comment.

Comment: @VolkerK  I agree, the output does suggest that $value2 does not contain line-feed/-break characters. But I think it does/should contain them.  The line-feed/-break characters came from the <textarea> input form, where I had entered lines of text and pressed [enter] as well.  When I output the data that $value2 contains, to <textarea> for editing, it does not show a backslash followed by `r` and backslash followed by `n`, it shows line-feed/-break characters as it should `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: Then investigate from what point on the string contains \r\n instead of carriage-return/linefeed characters. When I wrote "suggest" I really meant "it's blatantly obvious and unambigious" ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK  The point on the string containing \r\n is the beginning point, `$value2[0]` = \ and `$value2[1]` = `r`.  I do not understand how carriege-return/linefeed characters can become literally \r\n and than back again.  For example, `preg_replace` treats `\r\n` as those 4 literal characters, but when outputting $value2 unfiltered inside a <textarea> tag, it is treated as carriage-return/linefeed characters.

Comment: No, it's not about preg_replace. var_dump($value2) already shows that there are literal \ r \ n characters in the string - The actual output shows that _and_ the string length (16). If there were carriage-return/linefeed characters in the string the length would be 12, not 16. And that happens before preg_replace.

Comment: Oh, I probably misread your last comment. if \r is interpreted as a carriage-return (CR) character or as the two character \ and r depends on whether there _is_ a interpreter (vs just the plain internal representation of a string). e.g. `<php $x = "\r\n"; ?>` - the php interpreter parses the string literal and one rule for this parser is "unescaped backslash + r -> CR instead of \ r". But if e.g. mysql returns the string `\r` in a result record it's just that string, a blackslash followed by r; no further interpreter involved. pcre interprets the _pattern_ but not the subject.

Comment: @VolkerK I see now! it's not about preg_replace.  I was way off.  The problem was in how I had retrieved the data from table columns.  I had created an array to store values in the database, and I had assigned the wrong keys to the array (where I should have assigned the values/column names to the keys). `while($newArray = mysqli_fetch_array($Execute)){foreach($TableField as $key => $value){$GoodData[$value] = $newArray[$value];}`

Answer (score 0):

See Comments.  I had created an array to store the column names from the database's table...

```
$Command = "DESCRIBE {$Table}";
$Command = mysqli_query($mysqli, $Command) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));

if($Command)
{
    $TableField = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Command)) 
    {
        $TableField[] = $row['Field'];
    }
}
```

...But the array that stores the values was assigned the incorrect keys:

`while($newArray = mysqli_fetch_array($Execute))
foreach($TableField as $key => $value)
{$GoodData[$key] = $newArray[$key];}`

...The problem disappeared when the array was assigned the correct keys:

`while($newArray = mysqli_fetch_array($Execute))
{foreach($TableField as $key => $value)
{$GoodData[$value] = $newArray[$value];}`